# MATLAB: Set current folder to script's locaton

Tags: path, matlab

I have a handful of scripts and data in different folders and I use `addpath` and relative paths very often. My problem is, this only works if my current folder is where the script that I execute is located. For example, if I execute script A which adds path X and later execute script B which lies in path X, Matlab doesn't automatically change the folder and relative paths specified in script B don't work anymore.

Is there a way to automatically set my current folder to the location of the script I'm executing?

/edit: I should note that I use these scripts on different computers with different drive names, so using absolute paths probably won't help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Put the following line in the script, it would set the current directory = script directory

```
cd(fileparts(mfilename('fullpath')))
```

Comment: This didn't really work. :-/ `Error using cd
Cannot CD to D:\[abridged]\analysis\main (Name is nonexistent or not a directory).` `main.m`is the name of the script, `analysis` the name of the folder I want to CD to. How can I get rid of the `main`? /edit: Found it by googling your solution, thanks for the necessary keyword: `cd(fileparts(mfilename('fullpath')))` does the trick.

Comment: oh indeed, better than finding slashes and trimming, i will edit the answer

Comment: This is good for most use cases, but unfortunately it doesn't work when running a section of a script with the 'Run and Advance' or 'Run Section' buttons.