# MATLAB: Change paths for files and scripts according to computer name

Tags: matlab, switch-statement

I am regularly switching between several computers (home and work) and I have come to realize the issue of not having the same paths for several Matlab scripts I am using.

I would like to know if there is a method to automatically change the path according to the name of the computer.

In each of my computers, I have a *startup.m* script that sets up all opitons by default. In this m-file, I retrieve the name of the computer and use it in a *switch* environment:

```
%% Startup.m : use this for all personal settings

username = getenv('UserName');
computername = getenv('ComputerName');
switch [username, '@', computername]
    case 'oh@ECOP-CEREFIM06'
        % do something in office...
%     case 'Catsh@HOME'
%         % do something at home...
    case 'ohubert@eco-pai04'
    otherwise
        disp('Oh no no no!');
    return
end
```

Then, in my script, I have an addpath that looks like (say) at the office:

```
addpath('C:\ohubert\documents\data')
```

and, at home, it should be like:

```
addpath('d:\olivier\documents\data')
```

Is there a way to make Matlab understand inside the script to change from one case to the other **without having to change the whole script** ? In some sense, I would like to only change the beginning of the path but not the end.

Also, I am working under linux on a third computer and any help as to how coordonate among the three systems would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you very much.

Kind regards,

Olivier.

Comment: Maybe you could use this to achieve the same goal: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15103440/matlab-set-current-folder-to-scripts-locaton

Comment: Are the calls to addpath() within the startup.m? If not, why are not using relative paths? (e.g. addpath('./code'))

Comment: @Dan, I had a look at that post but didn't meet my needs.

Comment: @DasKrümelmonster, no the addpath are called within the script, not the startup file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cannot you just define a variable like

```
datapath = 'C:\ohubert\documents\data'
```

respectively (on your linux computer)

```
datapath = '/home/hubert/data'
```

and then use the the variable in all functions?

```
addpath(datapath);
```

Plus add next folders using the (platform independent) MATLAB function [fullfile](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/fullfile.html)

```
f = fullfile(datapath,'subfolder','somefile.mat');
load(f);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I will indeed insert within each case of the _switch_ a variable as  startingfolder='c:\ohubert\documents' and, within the script, use the fullfile or [startingfolder '\data\subfolders']  Thanks again.